# Check if Download Manager downloaded the file

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager, android-install-apk

How can I check if file has been downloaded and run its installation? I have a code:

```
public void downloadUpdate(String url){

    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
    request.setDescription("Downloading...");
    request.setTitle("App Update");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

    String name = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, null, MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url));

    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, name);

    DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    manager.enqueue(request);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To check whether the download manager downloaded the file, you must implements your BroatcastReceiver.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)) {
        DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
        query.setFilterById(intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0));
        DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Cursor cursor = manager.query(query);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                int status = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS));
                if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    String file = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME));
                    // So something here on success
                } else {
                    int message = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_REASON));
                    // So something here on failed.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure whether you can install the APK programmatically. For security reason, I don't think you can. For application update, I think you should use google versioning control. When you re-deploy your app using different version number, the users should able to update automatically (unless user turn off at google play). Hope that this will help.

**Update**

You do not need to call the method that I mention. You just need to declare your broadcast receiver at your manifest xml file and DownloadManager will call at when download complete. The xml look something like below:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".BroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_NOTIFICATION_CLICKED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: How to call this method?

Comment: You don't need to call, just extends BroadcastReceiver and configure at your manifest xml. I had update the answer for more details.

Comment: can please how to check  for multiple file downloaded..i thing we have to use **while loop** i donot know how to use please update answer for multiple file sir...

Answer (score 0):

This is relatively an easy method. It worked for me:
You need to add the `<receiver>` tag in the manifest file as follows:

```
 <application>
 <receiver
            android:name= "com.example.checkDownloadComplete" <!-- add desired full name here --> 
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
 </application>
```

This will register a Broadcast Receiver for an event where your download is completed. This will call the `onReceive()` method in your class as soon as download completes. Remember that you need to `extend` the BroadcastReceiver class, but not `implement` it. I declared a boolean variable as a toggle to check completion of download.
Hence, your Java class will be something like:

```
public static class checkDownloadComplete extends BroadcastReceiver{

     public static boolean isDownloadComplete= false;

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         isDownloadComplete = true;
         Log.i("Download completed?", String.valueOf(isDownloadComplete));
     }

}
```

To wait until or check whether your download has completed from any other class, use the following simple code in the desired appropriate place:

```
while(!checkDownloadComplete.isDownloadComplete){

    // add necessary code to be executed before completion of download
}
//code after completion of download
```

But remember that if you need to check it multiple times in your project, then you'll need to reset the value of `isDownloadComplete` beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the system to notify you when a download is complete you can use the `BroadcastReceiver` solution.
However if you want to get the status of a download manually, you can use this code, you don't need to add a receiver to the manifest file.
N.B. the interface is added for testing purposes, you can discard it if you wish.

```
interface Downloader {
    fun downloadFile(url: String,folderName:String,fileName:String): Long
}

class AndroidDownloader(
    private val context: Context
): Downloader {

    private val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(DownloadManager::class.java)

    override fun downloadFile(url: String,folderName:String,fileName:String): Long {
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(url.toUri())
            .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
            .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN)
            .setTitle(fileName)
            .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "$folderName/$fileName")
        return downloadManager.enqueue(request)
    }


    fun is_download_complete(downloadId: Long): Boolean {
        val query = DownloadManager.Query()
        query.setFilterById(downloadId)
        val cursor = downloadManager?.query(query)
        if (cursor == null) {
            return false
        }
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cursor.close()
            return false
        }
        val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)
        val status = cursor.getInt(columnIndex)
        cursor.close()
        return status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL || status == DownloadManager.STATUS_FAILED
    }
}
```